# Online poker OS restrictions

Tags: online, software

I asked around websites that offer online poker in my country. I was always told that to play with them on a desktop, I would have had to be a Microsoft customer, or at least not a Linux user. Is this generally true worldwide, and if so, is it considered reasonable?

Comment: What sites and regions in particular are you talking about? WINE 1.7.31 and later distributions of Linux can run Pokerstars, for instance!

Comment: That is good info, thanks! Specifically I asked 888 in Denmark, after seeing that they advertise support for Linux. When I asked how that would work, they seemingly admitted that it wouldn't. Then I gave up on the sites that do not even go to that length.